# How to highlight the differences in nearly duplicate rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns of data. For each set of duplicates in column A, I would like to highlight the differences from the original duplicates.

For example

```
Name   Value1   Value2 
A      1        Cherry     
A      2        Cherry   
B      3        Rice     
C      4        Potato     
C      5        Potato       
C      4        Egg
```

I would like to highlight the number 2 for the A duplicates, the number 5 for the C duplicates, and the word Egg for the C duplicates.

What is the best way to do this while taking in a list of columns? For example, lets say I have a dataframe of 30 columns and I only want columns B, C, and D highlighted under this criteria.

Answer (score 1):

First use `groupby` and `transform` to get a boolean DataFrame showing which cells should be highlighted. Then `apply` a custom function to style as needed:

```
conditions = df.set_index("Name").groupby(level=0).transform("first").eq(df.set_index("Name")).reset_index()
conditions["Name"] = True

def highlight(srs):
    return [f'background-color: {"" if x else "yellow"}' for x in conditions[srs.name]]

>>> df.style.apply(highlight, subset=["Value1", "Value2"])
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to pass a list of column names into this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So let's say I have a larger dataframe, with another column: Value3, and I only want to pass columns Value1 and Value2 while still using the Name Column to check for duplicates? So only Value1 and Value2 get highlighted

Comment: @UmarAli - For future reference, please be specific in your post. You mentioned "several columns of data" but didn't specify that you would need to apply the formatting on specific columns. See the edit for your solution.

Comment: When I export to excel, the non highlighted cells show up as black.

Comment: @umi_zumii - Specify the fill color as white for those. Change `{"" if x else "yellow"}` to `{"white" if x else "yellow"}`

Answer (score 0):

Highlight may applied when you have small data that visible to human eyes

For your case, I suggest the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a']*2+['b']+['c']*3,
                   'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

dfn = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['name'], keep=False)].copy()
```

`dfn` give you the new dataframe that has duplicates. You may modify `dfn` to your need